# JavaScript click if clicked return true if not false

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm working on some selenium Java code and I'm executing JavaScript code using executeScript as below:

```
     WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(string1));
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", menu);
```

What I want to be able to do is detect if the element can be clicked, if the button is disabled then the click event wont fire so I need a flag.  The problem with JS is that a click event returns undefined.

So I need a flag inside my executeScript, for example:

```
     Object flag_to_stop  = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("<<something here if returns true string else returns false string>>, menu);

    while (Object.toString.equals(<<true string>>))
```

Then I can execute a while loop and if flag_to_stop is false, I can break;

Any suggestions guys??

This is mainly a JavaScript question, all the Java code has been provided.

Comment: I would think that an undefined error would mean you are trying to call the event on an object that has yet to be created. So figuring out if it actually exists before running the script would be a good start.

Comment: You can check if element is enabled or not before click using [`WebElement.isEnabled()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isEnabled--)

Comment: myButton = driver.find_element_by_id("buttonId")
if myButton.is_enabled():
    myButton.click()

This should do it and is there any specific reason you are using the JavascriptExecutor as you can use selenium to do the same.

Comment: @Arita since Im going through alot of websites, injecting JavaScript ensures that it works everytime

Comment: @KDJ there is also a functionality in JS to check whether element is disabled or not as [`DOM.disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can try following:

```
  boolean flag_to_stop = false;
  try{

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", menu);

    flag_to_stop = true;
  }
   catch{Exception e){

    flag_to_stop = false;
  }
```